# DigitalPersona SDK: Transfer EnrollmentForm image to another form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

**What I am trying to do...**

I am working on a project that incorporates the DigitalPersona SDK CaptureForm and EnrollmentForm. The project also includes a main form, which for the sake of this question we will call Form1. This form includes a picturebox, called picturebox1, and a button, called button1. When I click on button1, the following code is executed.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EnrollmentForm enroll = new EnrollmentForm();
    enroll.ShowDialog();
}
```

In the EnrollmentForm, I have the controls setup as provided in the DigitalPersona SDK. It captures the fingerprint fine in the picturebox, called Picture. What I would like to do, is make it so when I close the EnrollmentForm, the captured image in the picturebox is transferred to the picturebox on Form1.

**What I have tried...**

I have tried many examples I have found here on stackoverflow and Google. The first is to create a FormClosing Event and try to pass the image from the EnrollmentForm to Form1. I did this by making picturebox1 on Form1 public in Form1.Designer.cs and then putting the following code into the EnrollmentForm.

```
private void EnrollmentForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Form1 frm = new Form1();
    frm.picturebox1.Image = Picture.Image;
}
```

This compiled without problems, but once the image is captured and the form is closed, the image is never transferred to Form1. Doing further research, I found an article that suggested the following method when opening the second form modally.

In Form1, I modified the button1_Click to look like the following.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EnrollmentForm enroll = new EnrollmentForm();
    enroll.ShowDialog();
    picturebox1.Image = enroll.SelectedImage;
}
```

Then in the EnrollmentForm, the following code was added.

```
public Image SelectedImage
{
    get { return Picture.Image; }
}
```

Again, this compiled. The fingerprint was captured, but when the EnrollmentForm was closed, the image never transferred to picturebox1 on Form1.

I am really not sure what I am doing wrong here. Eventually, Form1 will contain more than one picturebox, and will utilize the EnrollmentForm to populate each picturebox. I appreciate any assistance.

**UPDATE for Future Readers**: Just thought I'd add what ended up working. Turns out that the EnrollmentForm from the SDK gets the picture from CaptureForm. I ended up having the button open the CaptureForm instead, and tried the image transfer to the main form and it works properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: Create a Image Type Public Variable like enImage into your EnrollmentForm and In your enrollment form Closing event set it like enImage=yourpictureboxcontrolname.Image ;

Step 2: In your Main Form create another image type variable called mainImage and in button click event add this code

```
EnrollmentForm enroll = new EnrollmentForm();
enroll.ShowDialog();
mainImage = enroll.enImage;
picturebox1.Image=mainImage;
```

I tested this code and it's working.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanation. Turns out that the main problem was EnrollmentForm gets the image from CaptureForm. I ran your code from the CaptureForm instead of the EnrollmentForm and the image now transfers properly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In your main form, create a property i.e.

```
    public Image img 
    {
        set { pictureBox1.Image = value; } 
    }
```

When you calling your 2nd Form within some event handler pass the reference of your current form on which you need to show the image i.e.

```
    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 fm2 = new Form2(this);
        fm2.Show();
    }
```

Within your 2nd Form, initialize Form1 with its reference which we passed

```
    private Form1 mainForm = null;
    public Form2(Form callingForm)
    {
        mainForm = callingForm as Form1;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Finally before the 2nd Form closes, set the image to the Form1 like

```
    private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        this.mainForm.img = pictureBox1.Image;
    }
```

This is tested code and It 100% works.
Hope it helps.